# MySQL/MariaDB slow UPDATE on PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, innodb, mariadb

Query:

```
UPDATE `cart` SET `user_id` = NULL, `completed` = 0 WHERE `id` = 6948;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.21 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

0 rows affected, but it took 1210ms. SELECT of this row by id always took 0ms.
Table size is (6,354 rows).

```
> show create table cart;
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'флаг, указывающий на оформление заказа из данной корзины',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6964 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

> show index from cart;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cart  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |        6386 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cart  |          1 | user_id  |            1 | user_id     | A         |        2128 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Here is the excerpt from `show profile all` for this query

```
| Status               | Duration | CPU_user | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function       | Source_file   | Source_line |

| query end            | 2.502555 | 0.003000 |   0.000000 |                88 |                   8 |             0|           136 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc  |        5093 |
```

Why block_ops_out is so inconsistant, from 0 to 400, taking 0ms ~ 2500ms ??? How to find the root cause for it to be high?

Server version: 10.0.17-MariaDB-1~wheezy. The VPS has not any noticeable load at all.

**UPD:** added status vars after the query:

```
MariaDB> flush status; UPDATE `cart` SET `user_id` = NULL, `completed` = 0 WHERE `id` = 6948; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.54 sec)

^[[A^[[BQuery OK, 0 rows affected (3.88 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 2     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 0     |
| Handler_icp_attempts       | 0     |
| Handler_icp_match          | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_key_refills    | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_rowid_refills  | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 2     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 1     |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_deleted   | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_update         | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_write          | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 1     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: My first guess: You set the `user_id` which belongs to an index, so the index has to be rebuild. But 1 sec for lousy 6k records is odd. Maybe an update trigger running in behind?

Comment: @juergend No update triggers, generally there are no triggers at all in the whole db.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE` !

Comment: Something strange is going on.  Could you rerun thus:  `FLUSH STATUS; UPDATE ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`  The handler counts may give us some surprising information.

Comment: @RickJames done. btw, It took me at least 20 runs, until I got 3.88sec :) All the previous runs were ~1ms.

Comment: I have to believe that something else was locking out the UPDATE for 3.88 seconds.  Perhaps a another mysql connection.  Perhaps some other process.  Oh, one more thing to check -- was there any swapping?

Comment: @RickJames nope, no swapping, RAM is half free. No load at all. Furthemore this tests i've done on the backup db, so, there was only me connected. The reason is huge amount of context switching, which in case I believe is caused by fail to lock (block_opts_out tells this). But why there are so many block_opts_out - that's the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in MySQL / MariaDB, but in OpenVZ and the IO scheduling on the server. After migrating to more productive disks the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is trying to migrate your table and data into Mysql MyIsam engine and execute the same query. Maybe you just found a weak-point of MariaDB or something is misconfigured or overtuned.

Comment: MyISAM is very likely to be worse than InnoDB.  This is because of MyISAM's table locking.

Comment: This locking shouldn't affect single row update execution time noticeably. I just wanted to exclude possible bottlenecks in this test. And I guess I could came up to the same solution.